# Multithread: Explicit locks

Tags: java

I have a question about this lines of code:

```
class S1Es3SharedState {
    //lock
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private int x = 0;

    public int getX() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return x;
        } finally  {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void incrementX() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.x = x++;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

the same object locks the statments in the method **getX** and in the method **incrementX**
what it mean?
If i understand it means that the same object is used to lock the statment of both methods, so, a thread can enter in one of these methods if both are free, it's right?
example:
ThreadA is inside in the **getX** method,  now there is a context-switch so the ThreadA is waiting (inside the method) and the ThreadB is running and wants to enter in the **getX()** method but it can't because there is already the ThreadA. Also if the ThreadB needs to enter in the **incrementX** method still it cannot because the ThreadA is inside in the **getX** method. So the lock object i used allows to enter a thread just if both the methods are free (without threads that are running). it is possible? And this happen because i used the same object to lock **getX and incrementX** methods.

Comment: Just a side comment that nothing has to do with your question... do you realize that `this.x = x++` is more verbose and weird than just `x++`?

Comment: yes but i did it with eclipse  (in an automatic way) very fast just to put an example, in every case i know that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that two different threads T1 and T2 cannot be getting
and incrementing the variable at the same moment of time.

Simply put `return x;` and `this.x = x++;` cannot be executed
at the same time by two different threads T1 and T2. The thread
which enters first wins, only when it's done and calls unlock,
the second one will have the chance to obtain the lock himself
and do his job.

Comment: Thanks, in  one way like traffic lights that when enter T1 or T2 in one of this 2 methods... this traffic light is Red and will be green when both methods are free it's right? this traffic light controls 2 street (the methods) and just when both street are free the light is green. can i imagine in this way?

Comment: Yes, I find this a good analogy. The lock object is just one, the lock object is the traffic light. The methods are the two streets.